# Angular 2 dependency injection not working on service

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I am trying to get static data from UserService in Angular 2. Everything looks ok from the documentation but it is not working for some reason.

Here is my UserComponent.ts

```
import {Component ,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from './users.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'users',
      template: `<h3>Users </h3>
      <ul> 
        <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user}}</li>
      </ul>
       `,
      providers:[UsersService]
    })
    export class UsersComponent {
        users;
        title;

        construct( usersService: UsersService){
           this.users=usersService.getUsers();
// i also tried this but no luck. this.users = this.usersService.getUsers();
        }

    }
```

And here is my UsersService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    users =['krishna','ravi','ram','ramesh','sita'];
          getUsers()  {
            return this.users ;
        }

}
```

As expected its output should be

```
<h3>Users </h3>
  <ul>  
    <li>Krishna</li>
    <li>Ravi</li>
    <li>Hari</li>
    <li>etc</li>
  </ul>
```

But it is not repeating on *ngFor loop. I printed {{users}} as well and it returns empty. Please suggest me what is the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is spelling mistake for `constructor`

```
export class UsersComponent {
  users;
  title;

  constructor( private usersService: UsersService) {        
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.usersService.getUsers();
  }
}
```